# Installing Babel V6.x ES7 Async/Await on Node.js v6.2.0 with Nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

Man is this a pain to setup! I've followed the installation instructions here clicking on the nodemon box:

https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

```
npm install babel-cli babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

`.babelrc` in root directory:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator"]
}
```

`package.json` (I've installed more babel stuff as seen):

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.11.4",
  "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
  "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.8.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
  "babel-preset-node6": "^11.0.0",
  "babel-register": "^6.11.6"
},
"scripts": {
  "startn": "nodemon app.js",
  "babel-node": "babel-node --presets=es2015 --ignore='foo|bar|baz'",
  "babel-dev": "nodemon --exec npm run babel-node -- experiment/socketio/test.js"
},
...
```

`test.js`:

```
(async function () { // <-- error occues here
    const value = await 123;
    console.log(value);
})().then(() => {
    console.log('Done');
});
```

I run the command `run-script babel-dev` as seen below. Error:

```
karl@karl-ux303ln:~/dev/sketch$ npm run-script babel-dev

> sketch@0.0.1 babel-dev /home/karl/dev/sketch
> nodemon --exec npm run babel-node -- experiment/socketio/test.js

[nodemon] 1.10.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `npm run babel-node experiment/socketio/test.js`

> sketch@0.0.1 babel-node /home/karl/dev/sketch
> babel-node --presets=es2015 --ignore='foo|bar|baz' "experiment/socketio/test.js"

/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:591
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /home/karl/dev/sketch/experiment/socketio/test.js: Unexpected token (1:7)
> 1 | (async function () {
    |        ^
  2 |     const value = await 123;
  3 |     console.log(value);
  4 | })().then(() => {
    at Parser.pp.raise (/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:22:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:89:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:83:33)
    at Parser.pp.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:582:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:481:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:277:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:257:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:188:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:165:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/home/karl/dev/sketch/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:128:19)

npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-65-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/karl/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/node" "/home/karl/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/npm" "run" "babel-node" "experiment/socketio/test.js"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! sketch@0.0.1 babel-node: `babel-node --presets=es2015 --ignore='foo|bar|baz' "experiment/socketio/test.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sketch@0.0.1 babel-node script 'babel-node --presets=es2015 --ignore='foo|bar|baz' "experiment/socketio/test.js"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the sketch package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel-node --presets=es2015 --ignore='foo|bar|baz' "experiment/socketio/test.js"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs sketch
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sketch
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/karl/dev/sketch/npm-debug.log
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've also tried switching to node v4.4.7 and upgrading npm to 3.10.6. still same error.

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7, it's a proposal.

Comment: @FelixKling Indeed it is, but you understand what I mean :)

Comment: Please try to avoid using offensive words/phrases in your questions

Comment: @rossipedia I don't find the word "retarded" offensive, it's an 
interpretive question. There are worse words out there you should worry more about.

Comment: Neither do I, honestly. But that really [isn't the point](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: *"The "duplicate post" answer isn't helpful"* and yet you are configuring Babel exactly as described in that post...

Comment: @FelixKling IF you understand what that post is saying. Sorry Felix, but I don't time to dive into the mechanics of Babel, I just need some ES7 things to work so I can focus on what I DO best.

Comment: *"The quickest way to get this working is to use presets which already contain the set of plugins needed to transform ES2015 and newer proposals. For async, you will need the es2015 and stage-3 preset and the runtime plugin."* That's all you needed from that answer. Is it not clear that what means? Either way, glad you figured it out.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not saying that the answer presented was *bad*, it just didn't answer *my* question. True it did state those things, however it failed to mention `babel-register` for example, and the presets to be set in `.babelrc`. Also thanks for removing the duplicate, I'll update this question with the appropriate answer now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) remove all babel modules (remove **everything**, this is a little buggy I've found out)

2) install the following:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-3 babel-register
```

3) fix .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-3"
  ]
}
```

4) check to see if it works (`-r` flag is to preload modules):

```
node -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill experiment/socketio/test.js
```

To fix nodemon:

```
nodemon -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill experiment/socketio/test.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Async/await is handled in babeljs by the plugin `transform-async-to-generator`, which is included in the `stage-3` preset. It's *not* included by default in the `es2015` preset, so you'll have to add either the plugin itself or the `stage-3` preset explicitly. To do that on the command line, change this line in `package.json`:

```
"babel-node": "babel-node --presets=es2015 --ignore='foo|bar|baz'",
```

to read:

```
"babel-node": "babel-node --presets=es2015,stage-3 --ignore='foo|bar|baz'",
```

adding the `stage-3` preset. The same could also be achieved like so:

```
"babel-node": "babel-node --presets=es2015 --plugins=transform-async-to-generator --ignore='foo|bar|baz'",
```

However, it's generally recommended practice to use the `.babelrc` configuration file, which could be as simple as:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-3"]
}
```

or

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator"]
}
```

and then the line in your `package.json` could just be:

```
"babel-node": "babel-node --ignore='foo|bar|baz'",
```

---

(original answer for comment context)

You need to add:

```
"plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator"]
```

to your `.babelrc`, as I don't believe async/await is included in any of the standard presets (since it can be implemented in multiple ways)

Comment: Pretty sure async/await is in stage-1 or stage-2.

Comment: Ok added it, still doesn't affect anything :/

Comment: As far as proposals go yeah, but the implementation isn't. Parsing the syntax may be included, but the transform itself isn't.

Comment: Yes it is: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/ (it's stage-3 actually)

Comment: I fixed it! Check the bottom of the question to see :)